# How to insert JSON field with '&'

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle19c

While trying to insert JSON field "JAVA & ORACLE" in oracle 19c table, the concurrent program ends in error but the field is inserted in the table as "JAVA SELECT :ret from DUAL". Is there way to insert the data correctly while running the program from frontend.

> Incorrect data inserted on table as "JAVA    SELECT :ret FROM DUAL;"
> Expected data to be inserted "JAVA & ORACLE"

I am parsing the JSON field as below:

```sql
WITH json AS
( SELECT pin_clob doc FROM dual
)
SELECT Column1 ,
FROM json_table(
(SELECT pin_clob doc FROM json
),'$.Data\[\*\]' COLUMNS ( Column1 VARCHAR2(70) PATH '$.Column1'));
```

Fields in JSON extract we get from third party - "Column1":"JAVA & ORACLE"
When i try to insert this in our tables i get
Database response : Enter value for ORACLE

Comment: where is the INSERT code, and what application are you calling it with?

Comment: The question is not related to Oracle as long as Oracle doesn't interpret anything and is pure backend that processes everything it received as is. TOAD, SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer and other *tools* are just an interface to this backend and *may* introduce their own preprocessing of the SQL code. Please add more details about your application that passes the statement to a database and describe what is that `select :ret from dual` (maybe it's present somewhere in your code?)

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with complete details of the problem as you talk about inserting but your query is all about selecting and you have not provided any details of how you are trying to insert the data or what error you get when trying to insert the data.

Comment: SEQUENCE :
1. Call the API from EBS. We are consuming an API to get data from third party.
2. Receive JSON extract in a CLOB variable. This JSON extract has many fields. One of which has column1 value as "JAVA & ORACLE"
3. Parse JSON data in a cursor which will then be used to insert in oracle tables.
4. The moment oracle starts reading the JSON extract, it treats "& ORACLE" as a variable and asks for its value. This inserts "JAVA SELECT :ret from DUAL" which is nowhere in the JSOn extract,

Answer (score 0):

> Is there way to insert the data correctly while running the program from frontend.

You are not `INSERT`ing data; you are `SELECT`ing data.

Your query is not valid as:

1. You are trying to `SELECT pin_clob doc FROM DUAL` and the `DUAL` table only has the `DUMMY` column and not `pin_clob`; and
2. The sub-query factoring clause aliases `pin_clob` to `doc` and then in the final query you `SELECT` from the sub-query factoring clause and try to select the `pin_clob` column; but that will not exist as you have aliased it to something else.